# Do consensus-clients connect with any discv5 peer or is there any optimization?

Tags: consensus, eth-2.0, clients, validators, libp2p

I am looking at optimising connections between validators, and I was wondering how eth2 consensus clients handle this currently.

Reading the specs at [consensus-specs](https://github.com/ethereum/consensus-specs) I couldn't find anything very specific. I just found that consensus clients use libp2p and that they should use discv5 discovery.

Now, if they'd use "plain" discv5 discovery, I assume there would be no distinction: any peer using discv5 would be considered peer, disregarding if it's a validator or not.

Is there any optimisation for connecting validators in the p2p layer? If it's not in the specs (but maybe I just missed it), then I assume any client would be free to be implementing something custom. Then there would be no "general" answer and it would be specific to each client.

I am equally interested in pointers to spec(s), implementation or even implementation suggestions.

Thanks.